# Static Code Analysis Rules for 32 bit to 64 bit Migration

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2013, 32bit-64bit, code-analysis, static-analysis

We have legacy MFC C++ Code for 32 bit system, currently we are in process of migrating this application from 32 bit to 64 bit. In this process we want to use visual studio analyzer for finding issues related to migration. Can  please suggest which rules we can configure for this process ?  Any custom library for static code analysis for Visual Studio Analyzer will also be of great help.

Comment: Just enable "Code Analysis" in project settings. Keep all rules.

Comment: Don't want all rules need only rules related to 32 bit to 64 bit migration

Comment: If you are willing to ignore other issues, then why do analysis half baked? Don't do it then.

Comment: Seven Steps of Migrating a Program to a 64-bit System: http://www.viva64.com/en/a/0042/